# Gradient and Hessian of Nonlinear vector function.

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

I would like to develop a formula for the Gradient and Hessian of $f(x)= \phi(Ax)$
where $f $  is a nonlinear vector function $x$ is a vector $A$ is a matrix and $\phi$ is a nonlinear vector function.

$x$ is a vector in $R^n$.

$A$ is an $m*n$ real matrix.

$\phi$ is nonlinear vector function from $R^n$ to $R$

I tried the following:
$Ax=u$

$du=Adx$

$df=<\nabla \phi,du>$

but how can I achieve from that the Gradient and Hessian of $f$?

Answer (score 3):

You know the gradient $(g)$ and Hessian $(H)$ of a function $(f)$ with respect to the variable $u$.

And now you want to find the gradient $(p)$ and Hessian $(Q)$ with respect to a new independent variable $(x)$, which is related to the original variable by 
$$\eqalign{
 u &= Ax \cr
du &= A\,dx \cr
}$$
For convenience, let me denote the inner/Frobenius product by a colon rather than angle brackets. To find the new gradient, start with the differential of the function and then switch to the new independent variable
$$\eqalign{
  df &= g:du = g:A\,dx = A^Tg:dx \cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= A^Tg = p \cr
}$$
To find the new Hessian, start by taking the differential of the new gradient
$$\eqalign{
  dp &= A^T\,dg = A^TH\,du = A^THA\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} &= A^THA = Q \cr
}$$